# MYSQL select query based on another tables multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables one for units and one for Amenities

```
Table units
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
| unit_id |     date added      |     date modified   | unit name |   user   |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
|       1 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 |  Villa 1  | Smith    |
|       2 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 |  Villa 2  | Smith    |
|       3 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 |  Villa 3  | Jones    |
|       4 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | Apartment | Smith    |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+

Table Amenities       
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
|      id |  Unit_id  |   Amenity         |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
|       1 |         1 |   Air conditions  |
|       2 |         1 |   Internet        |
|       3 |         1 |   Water heaters   |
|       4 |         1 |   TV              |
|       5 |         2 |   TV              |
|       6 |         2 |   pool            |
|       7 |         2 |   Internet        |
|       8 |         3 |   Internet        |
|       9 |         4 |   Internet        |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
```

i want to select units where it has both TV and Internet

I try

```
select units.* from units left join Amenities  on units.unit_id=Amenities.Unit_id  

where Amenities.Amenity='TV' and  Amenities.Amenity='Internet'
```

but not work

Comment: what error comes from this query?

Comment: return empty string while it should return to units

Comment: you are passing `And` clause thats y

Comment: do OR there,
what you want exactly? 
a unit with both the Amenity or one of the both?

Comment: i want to select units where it has both TV and Internet

Comment: oh sorry my mistake

Comment: i will try your answer

Comment: @Strawberry I assume you mean because it's a pain if you now also want to find units that have Internet, TV and also Air conditioner? I agree.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry

Comment: @Wodin - yes - or if you want to find units that have 2 out of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS amenities;

CREATE TABLE amenities
(unit_id INT NOT NULL
,amenity VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(unit_id,amenity)
);

INSERT INTO amenities VALUES
(1,'Air conditions'),
(1,'Internet'),
(1,'Water heaters'),
(1,'TV'),
(2,'TV'),
(2,'pool'),
(2,'Internet'),
(3,'Internet'),
(4,'Internet');

SELECT unit_id 
  FROM amenities 
 WHERE amenity IN ('TV','Internet') 
 GROUP 
    BY unit_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
+---------+
| unit_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       2 |
+---------+
```

Obviously, you'd never have a table like the one you describe. Instead, you'd have a table of unit, a table of amenities, and a table which says which amenity belongs to which unit.

Comment: I agree that it's better to have an `Amenties` table that only has `amenity_id` and `amenity` columns and then a linking table with `unit_id` and `amenity_id`. Then `Amenities` would only have one record for e.g. `Internet`, but there would be a record in `unit_amenities` for each unit with the `Internet` amenity.

Comment: @Wodin Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ua.*
FROM units AS ua
INNER JOIN units AS ub ON ua.unit_id = ub.unit_id
INNER JOIN Amenities AS aa
    ON ua.unit_id = aa.Unit_id
    AND aa.Amenity = 'TV'
INNER JOIN Amenities AS ab
    ON ub.unit_id = ab.Unit_id
    AND ab.Amenity = 'Internet';
```

Here's the output generated with your data:

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+
| unit_id | date added          | date modified       | unit name | user  |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+
|       1 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | Villa 1   | Smith |
|       2 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | Villa 2   | Smith |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, i found that his answer is petter